# How does Psionic Shot work with Aegis Energy Blast, Improved Ranged Attack, & Empowered Blast suit mod?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics

- Psionic Shot: use psionic focus +2d6 damage to a range attack
- Energy Blast, Improved Ranged Attack & Empowered Blast Attack deals 2d6 + 1d6/5Lvs +1d6/PP
- This combination attack is delivered via a touch attack. Now since it say "Ranged touch attack", does Psionic Shot and Greater Psionic Shot apply normally.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Psionic Shot nor Greater Psionic Shot apply, because those apply specifically to “your attacks with a ranged weapon,” and the ranged customizations are not weapons.

Comment: Are there there no other ways besides using PP1/+1d6 to increase Aegis Range capabilities?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Very limited. Bonuses that apply to just “damage” as well as those that apply to “attack damage” and “ranged attack damage” would apply to these customizations, because it is damage and you do make a ranged attack. But such general bonuses are relatively rare and tend to be relatively small.

Comment: Would Deadly Aim feat work? Feat does say "ranged attack rolls" and doesn't mention any weapons, meaning you should be able to do this with the Aegis ranged attacks (both physical and energy) and probably ray based attack from spell and powers.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Yes, Deadly Aim is broader and applies to all ranged attacks, including the aegis’s ranged attack and energy blast as well as ranged attacks, such as rays, from spells and powers.