# Can the Aegis Ranged Attack be used Psionic Shot and Greater Psionic Shot?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, psionics

> #### Ranged Attack
>
> The aegis gains the ability to propel a **non-psionic crystal**, formed from the astral suit, at a target as a ranged attack that deals **1d8 points of piercing damage and has a range increment of 30 ft**.

Does this count as a ranged weapon for the purpose of using the Psionic Shot feat? I asked a similar question with the Energy Blast option and [KRyan answered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/104841/4563)

> Neither Psionic Shot nor Greater Psionic Shot apply, because those apply specifically to “your attacks with a ranged weapon,” and the ranged customizations are not weapons.

But I'd like to beg to differ in the case of **Ranged Attack** option as it produces a physical projectile to do damage in stead of an energy type form **Energy Blast.** The non-psionic crystal projectile should count as a ranged weapon for the purpose of the **Psionic Shot** feat. Though the source of the projectile via the suit is supernatural in nature, the crystal is and can be used a weapon ( maybe using ammunition rules).

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s still not a weapon, any more than the *crystal shard* power is a weapon.

Something is a weapon if it appears in the weapons list, or explicitly states that it is a weapon. Nothing else is a weapon.

It is worth noting that in D&D 3.5, this was different. The *Complete Arcane* supplement covered “weapon-like spells.” Strictly speaking, that still wouldn’t cover the aegis’s ranged attack, since it is a supernatural ability rather than a spell, but it’s certainly much *closer* to being legal.

Comment: Its an Improvised Weapon adding the feat should now qualify it for the feat if really needs to be that anal about it. Obsidian a type of crystal are used for   arrow and spear heads and proto hand held slashing weapons a kin to daggers and knives. What does PC have to physically throw the thing to count as a weapon. Sling bullets are rocks and they count as weapon with ammunition category.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver No, it’s not—again, no more than *crystal shard* is. You don’t take the improvised-weapon penalty with it, for example. In order to count as a weapon, *some rule has to say it’s a weapon.* In this case, nothing does. Merely making an attack roll and causing damage are insufficient; plenty of non-weapon things do that.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver I strongly recommend that you simply *ask your GM these questions instead of us.* The official answers are likely to be disappointing, since the ranged attack options of the aegis were designed to be minor in the extreme, because the aegis was supposed to be a melee powerhouse and any ranged options were decidedly secondary. But this was an “imagery” concern, about what the aegis is “supposed to be.” If your (and your GM’s) image of the aegis is different, if you think a ranged aegis should be possible, tweaking these is entirely valid, and probably not imbalanced.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver 1) Strictly speaking, Obsidian isn't a crystal- it's a glass, and glass is amorphous (not crystalline). 2) Sling bullets aren't rocks, they're lead bullets- using plain rocks imposes attack/damage penalties. The Aegis' crystal attack doesn't count as a weapon because it doesn't say it's a weapon. It is a Supernatural ability which happens to make an attack roll; it does nothing more or less than the ability itself states. (Though much more on this and we should be migrating to chat)

Comment: Actually pathfinder has weapon-like spells too: [faq](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9uxg). But you're right that it still doesn't apply to Psionic Shot.